# Saving to an object file in Java: getParentFile()

Tags: java, outputstream, mkdir, object-files

```
public void save() throws IOException {
            File f = new File(path);
            if (!f.getParentFile().exists()) {
                f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f, false);//overwrite, append set to false
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);

            out.writeObject(this.vehicles);
            out.close();
        }
```

I Have the following code that saves an object of type vehicule into a file. However, I don't understand quite well how it works since it was a sample provided for me, and since I am new in the java field.

I am wondering what is the interpretation of these lines `if (!f.getParentFile().exists()) {
                f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }` I am wondering what `getParentFile().exists()` does and why are we searching for the parent file while we are interested in the file itself. same question for the next line: why are we interested in the parent directory when we are going to create the file?
I would like to know also the difference between `FileOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` and why both are used one next to another in the following lines `FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f, false);//overwrite, append set to false
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);`
    Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are pointers to file or directory locations on a File System. If you intend to write to a file, though, the parent directory in which it will reside must exist. Otherwise, you'll get an `IOException`. The `mkdirs` call will create the necessary parent directory (or directories) to avoid that `IOException`.

I don't think the `exists` check is really necessary, though, since the `mkdirs` method returns false if it actually didn't create anything.

Also, you should close your OutputStream within a `finally` block or use the Java 7 try-with-resources:

```
try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f, false))) {
    out.writeObject(vehicles);
}
```

Comment: You should keep the `exists`, but also check the return value of `mkdirs` to handle the case where you don't have permission to create the parent directory.

Comment: Very good advice about always closing everything/releasing resources in a `finally`. If you're using JDK 7+, you can also use the "try with resources" construct which does the same thing but is much cleaner and provides the ability to get at "swallowed" exceptions.

Comment: Good point, Alvin. Updated the answer with the try-with-resources approach.